# How do I access css/scss with react?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I have a react component where I am trying to change the background color of the css when clicking the div.

I know you can set the color in the component, but I am using this component many times, and don't to make multiple component files with just a different color, and even if I did, I am curious besides the fact.

How can I access (or even console.log to figure it out on my own) the css file and its properties through the component?  Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the desired background color as a prop, and use internal state with an onClick handler.

**Container.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ClickableDiv from './ClickableDiv';    

const Container = () => (
  <ClickableDiv backgroundColor="#FF0000">
    <p>This is my text.</p>
  </ClickableDiv>
);

export default Container;
```

**ClickableDiv.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ClickableDiv extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
    this.handleDivClick = this.handleDivClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleDivClick() {
    const { backgroundColor } = this.props;
    if (backgroundColor) this.setState({ backgroundColor });
  }

  render() {
    const { backgroundColor } = this.state;
    return (
      <div style={{ backgroundColor }} onClick={this.handleDivClick}>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ClickableDiv;
```

Comment: Thanks!  This will definitely help in the future (I'm a rookie). Though in this specific case, I'm trying to see if I can access solely from the .css or .scss file.

Comment: @DORRITO No problem! I guess I'm confused about what it is you're trying to accomplish. Are you just wanting to console.log the style contained in the .css file, or are you actually trying to overwrite the style? If so, are you wanting to specify the background-color in the .css file?

Comment: My fault if it wasn't clear, thank you for your patience.  I only mentioned the console log as a way to debug (so I could figure it out myself is someone didn't want to explain a lot).
Basically, I have some squares, and each one is styled as a different color in the css file.  What I want to do is access and change THAT squares background color in the css file, and change it on click.  (so if there is a hardcoded red box, a click will change it to blue for example.)

I knew there were other ways to do it, but I am trying to practice accessing/changing the css file from the component.

Comment: @DORRITO I made another suggestion in a separate answer. Similar concept, but with the requirement of specifying all styles in a .scss file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep all background-color styles in your .css/.scss file, you will need to have a good className strategy to link the styles to your components. Here is my suggestion:

**styles.scss**

```
.blue {
  background-color: blue;

  &.clicked {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

**Container.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ClickableDiv from './ClickableDiv.js';

const Container = () => (
  <ClickableDiv className="blue">
    <p>This is my text.</p>
  </ClickableDiv>
);

export default Container;
```

**ClickableDiv.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ClickableDiv extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { clicked: false };
    this.handleDivClick = this.handleDivClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleDivClick() {
    this.setState({ clicked: true });
  }

  render() {
    const divClassName = [this.props.classname];
    if (this.state.clicked) divClassName.push('clicked');
    return (
      <div className={divClassName.join(' ').trim()} onClick={this.handleDivClick}>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ClickableDiv;
```

---

### Rendered Markup

Unclicked:

```
<div class="blue"><p>This is my text.</p></div>
```

Clicked:

```
<div class="blue clicked"><p>This is my text.</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to make an external css file and write your css code in that file and just import that one in index.html